# Is it possible to put a python dictionary in AMQP?

Tags: python, dictionary, amqp

Usually I'm used to putting strings in beanstalkc.  But I'd like to put a dictionary as a job in amqp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`json.dumps()`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dumps)